# jest - test coverage report from required file

Tags: jestjs

I would like to get the status of a file coverage report. I tried like

`yarn test --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=src/app/app.component.ts`

But it runs all files. what is the correct way to get the coverage from a single file. so let me my team member status.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my folder structure, there are two test files.

```sh
.
├── module.test.ts
├── module.ts
└── module.v2.test.ts
```

Now, I only want to run `module.v2.test.ts` test file and collect its test coverage.

`yarn test --coverage <file path>.test.ts`

E.g.

```sh
☁  jest-codelab [master] yarn test --coverage /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/timer-mock/module.v2.test.ts   
yarn run v1.17.3
$ jest --detectOpenHandles --coverage /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/timer-mock/module.v2.test.ts
 PASS  src/timer-mock/module.v2.test.ts
  use jest.runAllTimers
    ✓ calls the callback after 1 second (9ms)
  use jest.runTimersToTime
    ✓ calls the callback after 5 second via runTimersToTime (2ms)

  console.log src/timer-mock/module.ts:205
    Ready....go!

  console.log src/timer-mock/module.ts:213
    Times up -- stop!

  console.log src/timer-mock/module.ts:205
    Ready....go!

  console.log src/timer-mock/module.ts:213
    Times up -- stop!

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 module.ts |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                 5 |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.868s, estimated 10s
Ran all test suites matching /\/Users\/ldu020\/workspace\/github.com\/mrdulin\/jest-codelab\/src\/timer-mock\/module.v2.test.ts/i.
✨  Done in 6.08s.
```